# My form redirects the page to the API url used on the form (action="some url") after submitting, how to fix this? Django VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, html, django

This is what my page looks like: [image]

I have a sidebar which can change the contents of the page depending on the button clicked. When I click on About the page will look like this: [image]

So I made this with Vanilla JS using `inner.HTML`.

PROBLEM: When I refresh the page, meaning the `inner.HTML` is not happening yet because I never clicked any buttons on the sidebar yet. My form submits properly and it does not redirect me to the API url used on the form. But, when I tried to click the `About` button and click `Home` button and try to submit the form again, it redirects me now to the API page used on the form. My guess is, there is something wrong with my vanillajs using `inner.HTML`.

CODE looks like this:

HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}


{% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cms/cms.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}


{% block style %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/cms.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="sticky-sidebar-page">            
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h3>Manage Site Contents</h3>   
            <div class="list-group">
                <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" aria-current="true" onClick="showHomeContent()" id="homeButton">Home</button>
                <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true" onClick="showAboutContent()" id="aboutButton">About</button>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Contact Us</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Sample Page</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">A disabled link item</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sandbox">
            <div class="page-content" id="page-content">


                <!-- SCHOOL LOGO -->            


                <div class="card" id="school-logo">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5>School Logo</h5>
                        <small>On display:</small> <br>
                        <img src="{{logo.image.url}}" id="img" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="max-width: 10rem; max-height: 10rem;"> <br> 
                        <small>Change:</small>
                    <form action="{% url 'changelogo' %}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="logo-form">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" required id="inputGroupFile02">
                            <button type="submit" class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile02">Upload
                            </button>
                        </div>             
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- HOME CAROUSEL -->
                
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body"> 
                        <h5>Home Carousel</h5>
                        <small>On display:</small><br>
                        {% for pic in carouselpics %}
                            <img src="{{pic.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="max-width: 15rem; max-height: 15rem;"> <br>  
                            Label: {{pic.label}} <br>
                            Content: {{pic.content}}<br>
                            <span style="font-size: 20px;">
                                <span style="color: red;">  
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span style="color:brown"> 
                                    <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <br>    
                            <hr>
                        {% endfor %}

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const csrftoken = "{{csrf_token}}"
    //home contents
    var changeLogoUrlView = "{% url 'changelogo' %}"
    var schoolLogo = "{{logo.image.url|safe}}";
</script>
```

JS:

```
const pageContent = document.getElementById('page-content')

// Getting Home Page Contents
function getLogo(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/web-content/api/changelogo/"

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data){

        pageContent.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card" id="school-logo">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5>School Logo</h5>
                    <small>On display:</small> <br>
                    <img src="${data[0].image}" id="img" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="max-width: 10rem; max-height: 10rem;"> <br> 
                    <small>Change:</small>
                <form action="http://localhost:8000/web-content/api/changelogo/" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="logo-form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="${csrftoken}" >
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" required id="inputGroupFile02">
                        <button type="submit" class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile02">Upload
                        </button>
                    </div>             
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        `
    })
}

function showHomeContent(){
    if ( document.getElementById("homeButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){
        return;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('homeButton').classList.add('active')
    }
    if ( document.getElementById("aboutButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){
        document.getElementById("aboutButton").classList.remove('active')
    }
    pageContent.innerHTML = ""
    getLogo()

}

function showAboutContent(){
    if ( document.getElementById("aboutButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){
        return;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('aboutButton').classList.add('active')
    }
    if ( document.getElementById("homeButton").className.match(/(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/) ){
        document.getElementById("homeButton").classList.remove('active')
    }

    pageContent.innerHTML = `
        this is about content
    `
}

// formsssssss

// change logo


var logoform = document.getElementById('logo-form')
logoform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let input = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile02');

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('image',input.files[0]);

    var url = "http://localhost:8000/web-content/api/changelogo/"

    fetch(url,{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
        body:data
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data){
        getLogo()
        logo = document.getElementById('logo-div')
        logo.innerHTML = ""
        logo.innerHTML = `<img src="${data.image}" alt="no image provided" style="max-width: 7rem; max-height: 7rem;">`
    })
})
```

views.py:
this is the view I am using to for the change logo form where the problem happens when submitting after the page is rendered with `inner.HTML`:

```
class ChangeLogo(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = SchoolLogoSerializer
    queryset = SchoolLogo.objects.all()
```

Comment: You're replacing big chunks of your document with new HTML content in string form. This means `logoform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){` will no longer work unless you call it again on the newly added form. Submitting the new form will simply submit it the regular way, since it has no event handlers attached to it.

Comment: Note that creating a one-page website like that with vanilla JS is hard and unwieldy, it's why people came up with frontend frameworks like React or Angular.

Comment: ohh I see, thanks for this. How can I call the `logoform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){` to the newlu added form?

Comment: yes @ChrisG I understand that its better to use React, but with the timeframe I have I thinks it is not possible for me to learn and implement this project with React. Do you have any ideas how to do this with vanillaJS?

Comment: Wrap the code that you have at the end of your script, starting with `var logoform = document.getElementById('logo-form')` in a function and call it. Then, after `pageContent.innerHTML = ...` you need to simply call the function again.

Comment: Here's the basic idea: https://jsfiddle.net/mzh1f7kr/ (try to submit the form before and after replacing it)

Comment: ok thanks I will try to work with this. Please  give me a couple of minutes. @ChrisG

Comment: I can't make it work. :( @ChrisG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235174/discussion-between-jem-and-chris-g).